# Retired government employee keeps watch on a dangerous monster; sacrifices himself to stop it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in an anthology in the last 5 years; the anthology may have been published in the last 10-15 years.

I recall a retired government employee (possibly former MI6) who spends his time watching a dangerous creature disguised as an old man. The creature was previously taught code phrases to control its behavior.

The creature now goes to the store daily for groceries, but then something sets it off.  The retiree tries to stop the creature using a code phrase. He then contacts his former employer to obtain the rest of the codes from the Director’s safe.  However, there was a fire and the codes were lost.

In the end, he warns his daughter to leave town.  He then uses a final code which provokes the creature to kill him and return home temporarily.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to recall anything else about the anthology, maybe the cover or another story in it?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.